# Banshee deleted playlists keep reappearing

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, banshee

I'm running Banshee on a clean install of 64-bit 10.10. When I add my music collection (~110 GB) it crashes repeatedly. I eventually get it all loaded up after a few restarts. Then I delete the default playlists and make my own. Banshee is a bit buggy but I like it and I'm trying to make this work.

The problem I have is that two playlists keep reappearing after I delete them. Each time I restart Banshee, 'Favorites' and 'Recent Favorites' appear in my list of playlists. As soon as I click on them they disappear and the next playlist below is highlighted. How do I permanently remove them, so they don't come back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Banshee.  In general, AskUbuntu isn't the right place to discuss bugs.  It's better to report bugs to [the appropriate bug tracker](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/), however in this case, the bug has already been reported: [Bug 648634](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648634).

Comment: Thanks Michael.  As a workaround, I found that I could modify the existing smart playlists, since they couldn't be permanently deleted. I had been deleting them on install, and making my own. It works well enough that I just do it that way now.

Comment: Ahh, that's a good workaround.  Glad you found something that works! :)